# Node.js Express and Nexmo, how to connect a backed route to the Vue.js frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vonage

I have a working route in my app.js server, which send SMS using Nexmo via Postman.

```
const Nexmo = require('nexmo')

const nexmo = new Nexmo({
apiKey: 'myKey',
apiSecret: 'mySecret'
}, {debug: true})

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
// Sending SMS via Nexmo
nexmo.message.sendSms(
    '4542542445', req.body.toNumber, req.body.message, {type: 'unicode'},
  (err, responseData) => {if (responseData) {console.log(responseData)}}
    );
  });
```

What I am trying to do it to add button in my frontend which on a click would call the post method to send sms. This is my simple frontend code.

```
<template>

    <panel title="Send SMS

      <v-flex>
      <v-text-field
        label="number"
        id="number"
        v-model="reservation.telefon"
        ></v-text-field>

      <v-text-field
        label="message"
        id="msg"
        v-model="message"
        ></v-text-field>
      <v-btn id="button" @click="sendSms">Send</v-btn>
      </v-flex>
      </panel>

      </v-layout>
 </template>
```

My question is, how do I write a simple method to send an sms using Nexmo, where reservation.telefon is the toNumber and message is the message I am sending.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to implement a function in your vue code that makes a POST request to your node server. It would look something like this:

```
function sendSms(number, message) {
  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = console.log;
  httpRequest.open('POST', '/send');
  httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  httpRequest.send('toNumber=' + encodeURIComponent(number) + '&message=' + encodeURIComponent(message));
}
```

You would also need to change the frontend a bit to update the @click handler

```
<v-btn id="button" @click="sendSms(reservation.telefon, message)">Send</v-btn>
```

Comment: I have added the code based on your code and I run into these when I press the button. Does it say anything to you? I added the image link here https://i.imgur.com/50GqiZt.jpg

Comment: as an addition my client and server is located in separate folder if it helps